# Jquery - animate after redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to animate my page after the page was redirected using Jquery, the problem with my code is that it only redirects but ignores the animation code, how can I resolve this issue ?

```
  $("#menu a:first-child").click(function() {
      window.location.href = "https://www.mysite/blog";
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#mainwrapper").offset().top - 70},
          'slow');
  });
```

(The animation just scrolls down to an anchor with fluid transition.)

Comment: When you redirect, all scripts on the current page stop.

Comment: The animation needs to be done in the new page, your current script can't modify the destination page.

Comment: @Barmar What's the solution to make it work once I'm in the redirected page?

Comment: You have to modify the code of the redirected page. There's no way to do it from the first page.

Comment: You could use a "hash" to go to the right place on the second page directly (but without animation) : `window.location.href = "https://www.mysite/blog#mainwrapper";`. Maybe it's a good and easy compromise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect, your current script will stop. If you really one to do it, I think there is a way, I DO NOT recommend it, but it will do the job.
Before you redirect to the other page; I assume the new page is still in the same app, not a totally different website), you can set a localStorage variable. Then at be beginning of the JS file of the page you redirect to, check if that localStorage variable you have set in the earlier view is there, if it is, do the animation, then remove that localStorage variable.

```
  // js file of current view
  $("#menu a:first-child").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("animation", true)
    window.location.href = "https://www.mysite/blog";
  });

  // js file of redirected view
  if (localStorage.animation && JSON.parse(localStorage.animation)) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#mainwrapper").offset().top - 70},
      'slow', 'linear', function() {
         localStorage.removeItem("animation")
      }
    );
  }
```